# How should I describe good orientation in a computer language, in a CV?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to apply to a position that requires working with software developers.
I want to express the fact that I can somewhat understand the code and structure of a certain computer languages, for example, JavaScript.

How should I express this under my "skills" list?

For example:

> JavaScript (Good orientation)

might sound kind of weird. What's a better way to do this in one or two words?

Comment: You should [check the spelling of tech words](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Javascript) (Wikipedia is almost always correct). And avoid colloquial ones, like [MSSQL](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=MSSQL).

Comment: *"orientation"* sounds like a literal translation from some other (Germanic?) language (does not seem to be covered by the 11 entries in [the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orientation#Noun)). Is it? What scale of skill levels is it a member of?

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of way you could express it. You likely don't want to exaggerate your skill level in a CV, so choose according to your ability.

**If you have a very basic, introductory knowledge you might say:**

- I have a basic understanding of
- I have some exposure to
- I am familiar with

**If you have a slightly more detailed but still elementary working ability, you might say:**

- I have a working knowledge of
- I am well familiar with
- I have a practical understanding of

**If you were highly skilled, you might say:**

- I am fully proficient in
- I am qualified in
- I have extensive experience with

Comment: "I am well familiar" [seems to be a phrase that's only used in a few dialects.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/28954/can-well-be-used-to-mean-very-or-really-can-it-be-an-adjective)

Answer (score 4):

You might say that you have a "basic understanding" or "working knowledge" of JavaScript.

Comment: \*[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can only work against you.  Can you list the languages and instead let everyone assume you have a decent skill level?  Rating skills like this yourself isn't good evidence that you are actually what someone else would consider to be that level, and a CV is just to get your foot in the door anyway.